# How to use spread syntax as arguments in function of TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wanted use array as function's arguments.
So I used spread syntax as arguments like below.

```
const add = (x: number, y: number, z: number) => {
    return x + y + z
}
let array1 = [1,2,3];
console.log(add(...array1))
```

I ran my code, it didn't work and any arguments recognized in
methods.
I checked spread syntax correctly using by console.log(...array1) and then result is "1,2,3" as number.
So why spread syntax wasn't recognized as arguments?
Does anyone advise me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript tends to infer array types over tuple types if given the option. So if you want it to treat the array as a tuple, you have to say so.

```
let array1: [number, number, number] = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can also [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html), which makes array literals become `readonly` tuples.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3] as const;
array1.push(4); // error
// or
array1.pop(); // error

console.log(add(...array1));
```

By above way, you can make sure the length of `array1`

In following method, the length of `array1` would be **changed** at any time and will show no error about it.

```js
let array1: [number, number, number] = [1,2,3];
array1.push(4) // no error
// or
array1.pop() // no error

console.log(add(...array1))
```