# How can I pass an array as arguments to instantiate a class?

Tags: typescript

How do I pass an array as the arguments of a new class instance in typescript?

```
class ExecModel {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public role: string,
        public email: string,
        public phoneNumber: string,
    ) {}

const test = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
const exec = new ExecModel(...test);
```

I tried using a spread operator but it came up with the error:
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, except that your class is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use spread syntax as arguments in function of TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155412/how-to-use-spread-syntax-as-arguments-in-function-of-typescript) - I tend to favor the `as const` style as a fix when possible, but the accepted answer explains the root cause more directly.

Answer (score 0):

The error " A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts (2556)" occurs when we use the spread syntax with a function that expects a fixed number of parameters.

To solve the error, **use a tuple** instead of an array or type the function to use a rest parameter.

There are several methods to solve this error.

**Method 01 : Use a const assertion to solve the error**

```js
class ExecModel {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public role: string,
        public email: string,
        public phoneNumber: string,
    ) {}
}

const exec = new ExecModel(...(["1", "2", "3", "4"] as const));
```

**Method 02 : Type the array as a tuple to solve the error**

```js
class ExecModel {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public role: string,
        public email: string,
        public phoneNumber: string,
    ) {}
}

// ️ declare tuple instead of array
const myTuple: [string,string,string,string] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
const exec = new ExecModel(...myTuple);
```